# Get users permission change

Tags: desire2learn, valence

One of our customers is running LE 10.1 SP9 and the following Valence API call is not working for them:

GET /d2l/api/lp/(D2LVERSION: version)/users/(D2LID: userId)

In previous releases (LE 10.0 SP1 and LE 10.1 SP4) this API call worked without having to set the “Users->See the User Management tool” permission.  But now it appears that this permission is required to be set for the get user API call to work.

Was this permission change an intended change, or an oversight that will be fixed in a future update?  What release of LE 10.x was this permission change introduced?

Comment: Our own tests against a 10.1 sp1 and 10.1 sp11 instance indicate that the users API call does not, in fact, require the `Users->See the User Management tool` permission. How exactly are you making this call? Are you using query parameters to provide a filter of some kind, and if so, which? I've tested using a calling user with absolutely no privileges (except the privilege to manage own profile) and the call works at this end...

Comment: No, we are not using any query parameters. The exact call is GET /d2l/api/lp/1.1/users/XXX where XXX are the values of User.User.Identifier obtained from the result of GET /d2l/api/lp/1.1/enrollments/orgunits/YYYY/users/?roleId=ZZZZ where ZZZZ is the student role id. What we are trying to do is obtain the username (UniqueIdentifier), first name and last name of students enrolled in the course. The calling context has the Instructor role in the course offering YYYY and has the Manage Own Profile, View Other User's Profiles and all permissions on the User Information Privacy group...

Comment: ... This works on our own development servers, but not on our customer server unless the View User Management Tool permission is granted to the Instructor role.

Comment: My tests that show this working without restrictions were done with a set of internal app credentials against an internal build of the service, and thus not meaningful to reproduce the issue. This family of routes places further restrictions on non-internal service builds requiring the `See User Management tool` permission on the calling user's role.

Answer (score 0):

The various API calls that retrieve users from the user management service, including `GET /d2l/api/{ver}/users/{userId}`, should all be subject to the `Users->See the User Management tool` permission. This is an intentional restriction. This restriction should be in place on all platforms since the LE 9.4.1 release, in the April 2012 service pack (SP4 on 9.4.1). If you notice that this is not the case on subsequent platform releases, then this would be a defect that should get reported to D2L.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the User Management routes are intended for users that would have access to all users in the system. It sounds like you are looking for a subset of information about users that you would explicitly have access to through a course. If you are looking for information about users that your users have explicitly been granted access to information about through something like the ClassList, there is another route that may be more appropriate to use.

It is: GET /d2l/api/le/(version)/(orgUnitId)/classlist/

Note: This route is subject to User Information Privacy settings, as well as several configuration variables that control which fields are available (d2l.Tools.ClassList.*) If you can't see the field through the UI (ie username or orgdefinedid), then you won't get it in the API call either, so should adjust the permissions and config variable settings accordingly.